# Using MySQL in Cocoa app

Tags: mysql, objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to use MySQL in my Cocoa app that I am building. I've downloaded the C connector for MySQL, but I'm not sure how to do all the linking business, or then how to use it after it's linked.

Any help you could provide would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Well you'll have to link with the connector library statically, which means linking with a file with extension `.a`. You then need to include the headers in your project, then include them in the file you want to use them.

You'll have to show us some errors if you want more details, or if you have any more trouble.